# Input forms not displaying when read from another html file

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I am working on a program that teaches secure coding practices (AngularJS), and a part of this is allowing students to click on vulnerabilities in the code. The code is read in as an html file with spans around items the student clicks on, but I'm trying to make it more interactive with input forms that appear in the same window as that appear after a point has been reached.

I'm reading in a html file through JSON like so:

```
"code": "./securityChecklist.html",
```

No problems there. This is the file:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
void getNames(string[], int);
int getWhich();
string getName(int, string[],int);
const int SIZE = 10;

int main()
{
  int which;
  string names[SIZE];
  getNames(names,SIZE);

  which =getWhich();
  string aName = getName(which,names,SIZE);
  cout << "You choose name: "  << aName;

  return 0;
}


void getNames(string names[],size_t sz)
{
  for (size_t i = 0; i < sz; i++ )
  {
    cout << "type name # " << i+1 <<": ";
    <span class="span-Pgm1CL Pgm1CL-var-input-Pgm1CL">cin >> names[i];</span>
    <div class="clq">
        <fieldset name="q1">
            <label for="q1yes">
              <input value = "1" id="q1yes" type="radio">
              "Yes"
            </label>
            <label for="q1no">
              <input value = "2" id="q1no" type="radio">
              "No"
            </label>
        </fieldset>
    </div>
  }
}

size_t getWhich()
{
  size_t x;
  cout << "Which name: ";
  <span class="span-Pgm1CL Pgm1CL-var-input-Pgm1CL">cin >> x;</span>
  return x;
}

string getName(size_t n,string vals,size_t sz)
{
    if (n >=1 && n <= sz)
      return vals[n-1];
    else
      return "";
}
```

The **clq div** element is giving me issues. It should load a radio button..

```
<pre ng-switch-when="codeblock">{{ unit.code }}</pre>
```

But instead it gives me the labels, but no input form at all. All I want is that little radio to appear.

I know this should work within a `pre` tag, so is the issue loading with JSON? Something with Bootstrap styling? Angular JS??

Heres what I get:

[image: screencap of the lack of input forms]

Comment: What's the server language? C++, C#?

Comment: Put HTML returned by `./securityChecklist.html`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you use a `<pre>` tag? Do you need to show pre-formatted text/code or actual working HTML code?

If working HTML code is what you want, you can start with declaring the radio buttons correctly:

```
<fieldset name="q1">
    <label for="q1yes">
        <input type="radio" name="q1" id="q1yes" value = "1"> "Yes"
    </label>
    <label for="q1no">
        <input type="radio" name="q1" id="q1no" value = "2"> "No"
    </label>
</fieldset>
```

Please notice I added the `name` attributes to the input controls, or else they won't work properly (maybe you already knew that and just forgot it).

You might also consider using the HTML5 `<code>` tag. [Take a look at this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/code).

Please update me if that's not what you need, thanks.